# Excel - last modified macro not updating

Tags: vba, excel

I've created a Macro (found on stackoverflow) to show last modified date of the excel file within the sheet:

```
Function LastModified() As Date

   LastModified = ActiveWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Last Save Time")

End Function
```

However the cell which contains '=LastModified()' only updates if i click into the formula bar and press enter. Formulas are set to automatic.

I would like it to auto update every time the excel sheet is opened - is this possible?

Thanks in advance :)

Max

Answer (score 0):

Call your function in a cell like this to force recalculation on workbook open:

`=LastModified() + 0`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried it and unfortunately it didn't work for me. Upon saving and reopening it still shows the old date until I click into the cell and then press enter.

Answer (score 0):

After you set up the lastmodified() function in VBA, call it every time the workbook opens:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Call lastmodified

End Sub
```

I do not know exactly how to modify it after each save after the workbook opens, however if you have macros running in the file, then I guess you can call it after each macro you run, etc.